# using jquery for Calculate total images in <id>

Tags: php, jquery

I have one div and inside it I have some images for example `<img src= etc`

I want to calculate total number of images in that div. Also I want to save these images ID into mysql using PHP...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To count them, you can do this:

```
alert($('#myDiv img').length);
```

To grab all the ids into an array, you can do something like this:

```
var ids = [];
$('#myDiv img').each(function() {
    ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

or by using a [`$.map`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.map), as per @Russ Cam's suggestion:

```
var idsArr = $.map($('#myDiv img'), function(n,i) { 
                  return n.id; 
             });
```

and those will give you the count anyway, by the `length` of the array (provided all images have an ID).

It might be convenient to send them to the server as a comma-separated string, e.g.:

```
var idsStr = ids.join(',');
```

Comment: how about using $.map ? For example, $.map($('#myDiv img'), function(n,i) { return n.id; });

Comment: @Russ Cam - this is true, I've not used maps much, I'm going to steal that idea and put it into the answer, after upvoting your comment.

Comment: @karim79- with so much selector power and jQuery object property functions, I often find myself overlooking the utility functions, even though they are really useful :)

Comment: @Russ Cam - I know, it's ridiculous the number of things I've been doing the hard/old-school way only to be stunned when I come across things like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div > div > img').length
```

will get the number of `<img>` elements that are immediate children of `<div>` elements that are immediate children of `<div>` elements. You will need some way to uniquely identify the div with the images that you require, either through **id** (*recommended*), **class name** or **DOM position**.